# While reading line by line from input file.txt, how to implement the code corresponding to each line

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I use Python3.5

I already created 3 functions:

```
 def Insert(self, key):
 def Report(self, node, a, b)
 def Print(self, node)
```

But I need to read a lot of lines from input file.txt as:

```
I 20
...
...
R 17 27
...
...
P
...
...
E
```

To read the file.txt above, I use the following code

```
filepath = 'file.txt'
with open(filepath) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   cnt = 1
   while line:
       print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line))
       ine = fp.readline()
       cnt += 1
```

**Question**: While reading each line, I need to run the corresponding function and turn the result, before running the next line. But I don't know how to implement it in Python.

For example, when I read line `I 20`, I have to run function `Insert(20)` and it will turn me a result. Then I continue to read next line  `R 17 27`, to run function `Report(node,17,27)`. Then, I will read `P`, to run function `Print(node)`. Finally, when I read `E`, I need to print ("end of file").

I am really appreciated for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic example (Python 3.x).  I dropped `node` and `self` since they weren't defined in your example:

```
import sys

def Insert(key):
    print('Insert',key)

def Report(a, b):
    print('Report',a,b)

def Print():
    print('Print')

def Exit():
    sys.exit(0)

# Dictionary lookup of what function to call for each letter
dispatch = {'I':Insert,
            'R':Report,
            'P':Print,
            'E':Exit}

with open('file.txt') as fp:

    # Iterate and return the line number and line data for each line
    for cnt,line in enumerate(fp,1):

        # `line` already contains a newline so end is used to suppress a newline.
        print('Line {}: {}'.format(cnt,line),end='')

        # strip leading/trailing whitespace and split on whitespace.
        # First item to `cmd`, the rest to `data`
        cmd,*data = line.strip().split()

        # Lookup function based on command, then call it with data expanded as arguments.
        dispatch[cmd](*data)
```

Input file:

```
I 20
R 17 27
P
E
```

Output:

```
Line 1: I 20
Insert 20
Line 2: R 17 27
Report 17 27
Line 3: P
Print
Line 4: E
```

If you expect errors in the data file, write your functions to take variable arguments.  Example:

```
def Report(*args):
    if len(args) == 2:
        a,b = args
        print('Report',a,b)
    else:
        print('Report: invalid arguments')
```

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: I just copy your code and run, but it errors in function print.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.6, as stated in the comment about the print? :^)  If you are using a specific Python version, you should mention it in your question.  Tagging it both Python 3.x and Python 2.7 I get to choose :^)  I'm positive you can figure out how to fix it if using another version.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Thanks very much. I am using Python 3.5 now, and implement it in Spyder

Comment: @ChuongNguyen I fixed the line for Python 3.5.  Isn't the 3.6 format nicer :^)

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Thanks very much, I am trying with your code to my program, I will feedback later

Comment: @MarkTolonen:  It is no error appear, but it seems that I cannot run any my functions. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the line and making the function choice based on the first word on each line. Something like:

```
tokens = line.split()
if tokens[0] == 'I':
    # call insert
elif tokens[0] == 'R':
    # call report
```

and so on. The args will be in the other tokens, for example, the insert call could look like `Insert(tokens[1])`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I checked your code. It is simple but effective. However, it seem that your code when reading file is not line by line consequently, it jumps over 1 line. Do you know why?

Comment: @ChuongNguyen, my code doesn't read any lines. If you insert my code into your code, make sure it is at the beginning of your `while line:` loop, before the `fp.readline()` in the loop. The first execution of `fp.readline()` in your loop reads the second line. The first line is read by the `fp.readline()` that occurs before the while loop. While other answers are clever and elegant, I prefer simple approaches that are easier to understand and maintain.